# How to inspect the contents of a Flatpak runtime?

Tags: flatpak, flatpak-builder

```bash
flatpak install flathub org.kde.Platform//5.15-22.08
```

This sample command would install the KDE Platform Runtime. But how do I check what's inside of it? E.g. what binaries or libraries it contains (possibly after installation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtimes are stored in these locations (system and user installations accordingly):

```
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/
.local/share/flatpak/runtime/
```

For example the runtime files in question would be located here:

```
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-22.08/active/files
```